# Problem book for real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

What are some good problem books for real analysis for competitive exams like the NBHM, IIT JAM, and NET? I don't want a theoretical book and most of the standard book contain really less number of problems. Moreover, I do already have AMS problem book for real analysis and it is really good.
Please suggest me more books like this one.

Comment: Look up some PhD exams at universities.

Comment: Another baseless closing of a useful question.

Answer (score 3):

Polya and Szego, Problems and Theorems in Analysis, vol I & II.

A classic, but expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Try *Problems in Real Analysis:Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis* by Titu Andresscu. I don’t know if that is what you are looking to since I don’t know that competitions, but the problems are usually from other competitions as PUTNAM or IMC, and have the MO feeling.